# Want to stop autoscroll of scrollviewer in specific page wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, autoscroll

My ScrollViewer is placed in Shell.xaml file. I have multiple nested UserControls. I am showing my header on all screens which is common for all pages. When i go to home screen my scrollbar starts from header. 
Now when i search for record and get the result back some controls on my home page gets enable which automatically moves my scrollbar to bottom of my screen as focus gets change programatically. I want to avoid auto scrolling on my home screen but want it on all other screens. I have searched for many options i tried using 'RequestBringIntoView' to prevent autoscrolling, tried to focus again onto my header but didn't work.
Is there any other option to prevent autoscrolling for just one screen?
[Refer this image to understand the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGPUe.png)

As i am new to WPF, it will be very helpfull if you specify detail steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried lot of options to stop auto-scrolling but didn't work. Tried to add custom scroll behavior's but no success.

I don't wanted to add anything to xaml.cs file as per MVVM architecture but i have to add the 'RequestBringIntoView' event to stop auto-scrolling and it worked and i have to add it to shell.xaml file where scrollviewer was placed.

Answer (score -1):

It would be a lot more helpful if you would actually include an example of your XAML and the code behind.
I'll try to help the best I can. You probably want to add the scroll viewer element to your code, so you can adjust the properties to leave scrolling disabled.

```
<window propertyname="stuff">
<scrollviewer isEnabled="false">
//content here
</scrollviewer>
</window>
```

However, I'm probably wrong about a lot of this. The best thing to do would be to use Microsoft Visual Studio, it's best for WPF apps. You can easily take a look through the properties window by clicking on the item, and from there you'll be able to find the right properties for the scrollviewer. 
Hope I could help.

Comment: Sorry about my previous statement which is wrong. You should be putting everything  into a grid and from there you should be able to set the scrollviewer.